# Making API calls await

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, stripe-payments

I have this code:

```
function createPlan(amount) {
    return stripe.plans.create({
        product: 'DigitLead website evaluation tool',
        nickname: 'DigitLead website evaluation tool monthly charge',
        currency: 'cad',
        interval: 'month',
        amount: amount,
    });
}

var product = stripe.products.create({
    name: 'DigitLead website evaluation tool monthly charge',
    type: 'service',
});

console.log(time);
if (time === '1') {
    var amount = 1499;
    var days = 30;
    var plan = createPlan(1499);
}
else if (time === '3') {
    amount = 999 * 3;
    days = 90;
    plan = createPlan(999);
}

plan.then(p => console.log("p " + p));
if (typeof req.user.stripeId === undefined) {
    var customer = stripe.customers.create({
        email: req.user.username,
        source: req.body.stripeToken,
    });
}
```

It looks good, but the problem is, this code is asynchronous. So when I try to create a `plan` using the `product` variable, it doesn't exist.

I could use the `then` chaining, but it would be messy as all hell. I was trying to get it done with adding `await` like this:

```
var product = stripe.products.create({
    name: 'DigitLead website evaluation tool monthly charge',
    type: 'service',
});
```

, but node just said:

```
/home/iron/Documents/Projects/digitLead/routes/payment.js:46
var product = await stripe.products.create({
    ^^^^^

    SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

I don't want to use callback hell, so I don't really know what to do. In normal code I'd just write the function saying `async` and return a promise. Here, I'm using [Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/api/node) API, so I cannot really edit anything.

Comment: "node just said nope", seems like a great error message. If you specified what exactly it said, maybe we could help fix that.

Comment: It was a simple syntax error. I'll add it to the post

Comment: @Adriani6 I edited the post.

Comment: Your error message says it all...

Comment: Well yes, but the question was, how can I get around it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can only use await in async function. Therefore you may wrap it in a async IIFE:

```
var product = (async(name, type) => await stripe.products.create({
  name,
  type
}))(name, type);
```

Comment: Please reformat your answer to make it more readable for future users. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Wish it looks better.

Comment: That's way better. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`await` can only be used within an async function. So you will need to mark the function you are inside as `async`. If you are not inside a function, you will need to wrap your code into a function.

You will then be able to use either `await` on the code line, or use the Promise `.then` syntax. For example:

```
async function createProduct(name, type) {
    return await stripe.products.create({name, type});
}
```

Comment: Sorry can you give an example? I'm not sure if I get you

Comment: Edited the answer

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax error just means you need to mark the function as async. If stripe.plans.create is async, you can add awaitable to it.

```
async function createPlan(amount) {
    return await stripe.plans.create({
        product: 'DigitLead website evaluation tool',
        nickname: 'DigitLead website evaluation tool monthly charge',
        currency: 'cad',
        interval: 'month',
        amount: amount,
    });
}
```

Comment: I up-voted. I cannot see any down-votes on your answer

Comment: It has been removed. I guess that was for missed `await` in my example which I fixed post-downvote.